# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exception, typeerror

I tried to go through each line of the tsv file and check if each word exists in a dictionary. The function can extract word from each content in each row, but it fails when it looks for if a word exists in a dictionary.

`dic = {'films': '0', 'adapted': '1', 'from': '2', 'comic': '3', 'books': '4'}`

The csv file format = `[1\tcontent]`

```
def extract_feature(filename):
    with open(filename) as tsv:
        reader = csv.reader(tsv, delimiter = "\t")
        for row in reader:
            for word in row[1].split():
                if word in dict:
                    print(word)
```

Comment: it is `dic` not `dict`

Comment: To elaborate on Jeril's comment: you name your dictionary "dic": `dic = { ... }`. However, further down in your code you call it "dict": `if word in dict:`. You don't get an error for using an undefined variable, because `dict` is actually defined: it's the predefined dictionary type. But now you're trying to iterate over the `dict` type itself, rather than your `dic` dictionary, generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if word in dict:
```

`dict` is the dictionary type, similar to `list`, `int`, `float`, etc.

Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: Why are you answering questions with typo's, just close it.

Comment: @U9-Forward How would that help the questioner?

Comment: @JohnGordon - Stack Overflow is not a one-on-one tutoring service, it's a question and answer database. Questions are intended to be useful to more than just one person. Also, OP didn't even use `dict` as a variable name; it was a typo when attempting to refer to `dic`, so this answer barely even helps the questioner anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the typo is likely in his actual code, not just in the question as posted. TypeError is exactly the error you'd get from coding "if word in dict:" It seems very clear that the OP *did* use `dict` as a variable name.

Note that the comment being referred to is not from the OP. @John Gordon's answer directly and clearly points out the error in the OP's code.